# Middleman Blog - selecting articles based on category in frontmatter

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to get specific blog posts by category variable in the frontmatter of the blog and also by language defined.

```
category: review
lang: en
```

So basically select all articles in category "review" with language "en".

```
- blog.articles.select {|a| a.data[:lang] }.each do |article|
```

Kinda stuck here as I am not a ruby expert - learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
blog.articles.select do |article|
  article.data.category == 'review' && article.data.lang == 'en'
end
```

This will select all blog articles which have the category "review" and the lang "en".

Answer (score 0):

```
<% blog.articles.select do |article| %>
<% if article.data.category == 'review' && article.data.lang == 'en' %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```